# How to display image as an overlay while blurring the main browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm looking for an example that shows how to display an image as an overlay in a browser while blurring/greying out the contents from the main browser window, here's an example...

http://fstopgear.com/product/satori-exp/view

Just click on any backpack image, then click any part of the browser to close the image..that's pretty much the functionality I'm looking for, I'm assuming there's a script or package that provides such control?

Comment: The functionality is called LightBox, google away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of solutions to get this done in jQuery. Please have a look into the following url's:

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of solutions as jQuery plugins for this. What you want is called "modal" or "overlay" window.

I recommend FancyBox: http://fancybox.net/

But also check out ColorBox: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox